# Xcode 4 debugger breaks in wrong file

Tags: iphone, xcode, breakpoints

I have been searching for this problem for months in Google & Bing. Here's the thing:

1. I set a breakpoint in my .m file somewhere.
2. I run it.
3. The debugger just stops in a weird file like below:

   ```
   0x00003204  <+0068>  ldr.w  r1, [pc, #1000] ; 0x35f0 <-[WhatNotesAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]+1072>
   0x00003208  <+0072>  add    r1, pc
   0x0000320a  <+0074>  ldr    r1, [r1, #0]
   0x0000320c  <+0076>  blx    0x34f44 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
   0x00003210  <+0080>  str    r0, [sp, #152]
   0x00003212  <+0082>  ldr.w  r0, [pc, #984]  ; 0x35ec <-[WhatNotesAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]+1068>
   0x00003216  <+0086>  add    r0, pc
   0x00003218  <+0088>  ldr    r0, [r0, #0]
   0x0000321a  <+0090>  ldr.w  r1, [pc, #972]  ; 0x35e8 <-[WhatNotesAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]+1064>
   0x0000321e  <+0094>  add    r1, pc
   ```

I have tried clean, reinstall Xcode, and today, update to 4.2GM,
but it still bothers me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I hate when stuff like that happens as it is so hard to find the crash.  There may be better ways, but personally, I just set up `NSLog` files and check where they stop getting called, then narrow down from there by adding more `NSLog` files in the general area until I can find the line which crashes the app

Comment: well, that surelly works but takes too much time

Comment: It definitely does.  But unfortunately, I can't think of any better ways.  I'm going to +1 the question to hope it gets more attention and some simpler solutions

Comment: thanks slev，seems not so much people got this problem

Comment: Some questions: Where do I find this my .m ;-) What is about the call stack? ZombiesEnabled? Running on simulator or device? Different behaviour between both? Obj-C only or Obj-C++? Any exotic 3rd party stuff?

Comment: @Kay sorry I didn't mean my.m, it's ***.m in my project. ZombiesNotEnabled. both simulator & device are same behaviour, oc only and i don't think it's about 3rd part source.

Comment: Look at the build configuration in your current scheme. Sometime it defaults to the release configuration for me which results exactly in this behavior.

Comment: @floorjiann I just checked that. it is debug

Comment: When this shit happens to me, I start debugging it in gdb console. Once it stops at breakpoint, I manually open the right file, then type n in console and press enter for each step. Some times Xcode recovers itself and the debugger syncs visually with gdb commands. Also, you can use gdb "backtrace" command (or lldb "thread backtrace") to see the actual call stack.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger has been thrown off for me when the same method is being called on multiple treads.  I am also running xcode 4.2. If you can post you code and possible callers that could help get to the bottom of the problem. I also see assembly code when I step past the end of my code.

Comment: thanks for your answer first. but I really know that's not about my code, it's more like what @floorjiann said, something wrong with my develop tools. But it's so shit even I reinstall my Xcode can't resolve this problem. Not this project but ALL PROJECT in my computer. And everything is fine in my other computer...I think what I can do is reinstall the OS